# Nodejs backend receive empty req body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am still learning Nodejs and expresjs. By using react-facebook-login, a respond is successfully generated from the facebook api which contains email, userId and much more. In my client-side, I have an action to post request to the server which contain facebook login state and I have a nodejs server to handle facebook login and verification. But In my server-side, my req.body catch nothing which is an empty object {}. It keeps saying that it is a bad 400 request. In Postman, I can successfully catch it through the API. How do I fix this? is it possible to be blocked by facebook?

[image showing postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVXzB.png)

In my client-side -> action.js,

```
export const FacebookLoginAction = (facebookLoginState, FbAccessToken, history) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const Origin = window.location.origin;
            const res = await axios.post(`${Origin}/facebook-login`, facebookLoginState, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'accept': 'application/json'
                },
               FbAccessToken
            });
            const { data } = res;
            dispatch({
                type: UserActionTypes.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: data
            });
            toast.success(data.status);
            history.push("/");
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                dispatch({
                    type: UserActionTypes.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAIL,
                    payload: error.response.data.message,
                });
                toast.error(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

In my server-side -> app.js,

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(helmet());

// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!'
});
app.use('/api', limiter);

app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10kb' }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

In my userRoute.js,

```
const express = require('express');
const authController = require('./../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/facebook-login', authController.facebooklogin);
// rest router ...
module.exports = router;
```

In my authController,

```
exports.facebooklogin = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body); --> empty object

  // rest code
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(\`${Origin}/facebook-login\`)` to see the address? Is it correct? Also does this `console.log(facebookLoginState)` print what you expect.

Comment: The address is just localhost. The api request is correct but somehow req.body is an empty object. FacebookLoginState is an email handled by form submitting.